# Connection Refused in-cluster but Port Forwarding works in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I currently have the Hashicorp Vault helm chart deployed, v0.8.0. It works as intended, I can run `port-forward svc/vault 8200:8200 -n vault` and log in with `vault login -tls-skip-verify`, the pod isn't crashing, there are no problems.

I've been verifying configs in the cluster, so I wanted to test access to Vault from another namespace in the same cluster. `dig vault.vault.svc.cluster.local` resolves to the proper service construct. However, when I run `curl -v -k https://vault.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/sys/health`, I get connection refused.

I'm running an AKS Cluster on Kubernetes v1.18 with Azure Policy defaults and the Azure CNI. What would cause this connection refused problem?

Comment: Can you get NetworkPolicy objects from Vault namespace and paste it for information, that might have some hints!

Comment: your vault running on HTTPS? please try curl with HTTP instead of HTTPS. if it's HTTPS are you getting any bad certificate error ?

Comment: port-forward operates in the same network namespace as the container, so it can access things listening on "localhost" but everything else in kubernetes requires the container to listen on 0.0.0.0 to be accessible from outside the Pod

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment @mdaniel left was what led me to solving the problem effectively. I had removed the `address` and `cluster_address` fields in the TCP listener config blocks as I forgot Vault only listens on 127.0.0.1. I put those back in and it solved the problem.